# String replace a url with part of the same url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string that contains a random url:

```
http://google.com/vocab/prefix#Billy
```

That needs to be transformed so that everything up to, and including the first `#` is replaced with the value between the last `/` and the first `#` followed by a `:`.

The result would be:

```
prefix:Billy
```

More examples:

```
http://some.url/a/path#elephant --> path:elephant
http://random.com/cool/black/beans/thing#Bob --> thing:bob
```

I understand how to capture the prefix part `/([^\/]+(?=#))/`, but I'm struggling to do a string replace because I can't figure out how to capture the part I need to replace.

```
myString.replace(/([^\/]+(?=#))/, '$1:')
```

**I would prefer to use string.replace with regex if at all possible**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `replace` method you need to match all the patterns you want to replace instead of just the part you need to keep; Here are two options:

```js
let s = 'http://google.com/vocab/prefix#Billy'

// using greedy regex
console.log(s.replace(/.*\/([^#]+)#/, '$1:'))

// adapted from OP's attempt
console.log(s.replace(/.*?([^\/]+?)#/, '$1:'))
```

Note `.*` part to match the substring you want to discard, `()` to capture the pattern you want to keep, then reformat the output.

Comment: Thank you. I like your first option, easier to understand.

Comment: Glad it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var myString = "http://google.com/vocab/prefix#Billy";
var hashIndex = myString.indexOf("#"); // find where the "#" is

for(var i = hashIndex; i > 0; i--) { // loop from "#" index *back* to closest "/" symbol
  if(myString[i] == "/") break; // break loop when "/" is found
}

myString = myString.replace("#", ":"); // replace "#" with ":" as in your example

console.log(myString.substring(i, hashIndex); // output
```

Shortened:

```
var myString = "http://google.com/vocab/prefix#Billy".replace("#",":");
for(var i = myString.indexOf(":"); i > 0; i--) { if(myString[i] == "/") break; }
console.log(myString.substring(i, myString.indexOf(":");
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it would work, but I would prefer regex if possible.

Comment: A regex answer may be just as (or more) complex than this. Why regex in particular?